# Loop variable used in lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, closures, java-stream

```
Set<Malfunction> malfunctions= ...
for (final String guideword : guidewords) {
    Malfunction malf = malfunctions.stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getGuideword().equals(guideword))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .get(0);
```

When I avoid using the `guideword` variable, but use a hardcoded value, such as "some_reasonable_string" everything works fine.

If I use the `guideword` from loop the problem occurs: There is a `Set<Hazard>` which is and should be filled in *malfunctions*, but is afterwards empty in *malf*.

Comment: So what is this `Set<Hazard>` and what are you doing with it? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Aside, instead of `collect()` and `get()` you may use just `findFirst().get()` (provided that there is at least one element after filtering).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you mixing up two concepts? Iterating old-school; but then using streams?

Suggestion: use a stream-only solution; like:

```
final List<String> guidewords = Arrays.asList("A", "C");
Set<String> malfunctions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));

System.out.println(malfunctions.stream().filter(e -> guidewords.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0));
```

(simplified your input to put down an example that works for everybody; of course you have to adapt it to use `contains(e.getGuideword())` to match your requirement).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a loop variable from a lambda because it is not final. One solution is to take a final copy of it inside the loop.

```
    for (String guideword : guidewords) {
        // Add this.
        final String thisGuideWord = guideword;
        Malfunction malf = malfunctions.stream().filter(m ->
                m.getGuideword().equals(thisGuideWord))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

However, as GhostCat has pointed out, there may be a more fundamental issue here for you.

Comment: I was wondering why his code didn't work; I forget about that final thing. So, assuming you are correct on that part ... you got my vote for that ;-)

Comment: Also with the final copy the problem described above remains, unfortunately.

Comment: His loop variable _is_ `final`, so that cannot be the issue. Having a temporary `final` variable will not change anything.